Problem with quaternions/Angles flipping at 180 degrees
Ok I'm sure that this is a problem that a lot of people had in some form but i cannot find a solution.
Let's make a simple example of what i want to do. I have 4 bones, B1 B2 B3 B4. I want to rotate B4 along the yaxis by an angle alpha and make the rotation along the chain proportional, so B1 rotates by 1/4 alpha, B2 by 2/4 alpha and B3 by 3/4 alpha. The rotation mode of all bones is the default blender setting with quaternions. I have made some drivers to make the bones B1 B2 and B3 rotate.
Now if in pose mode I rotate the last bone around the y axis, let say i hit R Y 80 then the other bones rotate by 20, 40 60 respectively and everything is fine. The problem is when i want to rotate by more thant 180. Let say 200, then the bones should rotate by 50, 100 and 150. But blender converts 200 to -160  and the rotation of B1, B2 and B3 is in the wrong sense (-40, -80- 120).  I do not know how to avoid this conversion/problem, any idea?
So this is the result of my driver when i rotate by 90 degrees the bone in pose mode around the y axis.

the rotation angle is correctly computed as 1.57 radians or 90 degrees.
If rotate the bone by 270 degrees the result should be around 4.712 but instead is  -1.57 or -90

Since i base the rotation of all the other bones on this value I would like a way to get the total rotation, not the angle in the -180 to 180 range

I came across this post looking for how to set up drivers for rigs, so this is a bit above my  paygrade. But I do have experience with quaternions and bones flipping. So Just to make sure; are your bones constrained not to roll? Rolling bones might explain the flipping directions.

no the problem is that in quaternions the representation of let say 270 or -90 is the same but i need to differentiate somehow the two angles and i have no idea on how to do that
